# Github shared and self-hosted runners

Tags: github, github-actions, runner

I came up an interesting situation recently and I couldn't find something on that, so maybe someone who knows can share this info.

We have a github repository in a github organization. This has a set of GHA jobs (eg release.yaml) which are supposed to run on github shared runners:

```
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

The jobs were picked up fine, until I added a job that I wanted to run it on a self-hosted runner:

```
   runs-on: self-hosted
```

So I registered the self-hosted runner, the latter job got picked up just fine.
But when I came back to run one of the 1st stage jobs (ie release.yaml), the job wasn't getting picked up by the github shared runner as it is supposed to by the code, but was getting queued and waiting for a self-hosted runner to be available.

Has anyone seen this before? Is it standard behaviour or I should commit an issue with github?

PS: Deregistering the self-hosted runner from repository settings resolved the issue, but still, does this mean we can't have a set of jobs that some use self-hosted and some use github-shared runners?

Comment: Can you please create a reproducing example?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.